# React testing structure using Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme

I have a react component that I want to test the structure.

So when I run `wrapper.debug()` it shows me an output like this.

```js
<Fragment>
  <div className="SignupLoginContainer">
    <div className="SignupLoginContainer__SliderBtnContainer">
      <LoginSignupSliderButton toShow={[Function: toShow]} />
    </div>
    <div className="SignupLoginContainer__Form_Container">
       <Login isLoggingInOrSigningUp={true} />
     </div>
    </div>
</Fragment>
```

Then I'm testing it like:

```js
expect(wrapper.matchesElement(
  <Fragment>
   <div className="SignupLoginContainer">
     <div className="SignupLoginContainer__SliderBtnContainer">
      <LoginSignupSliderButton toShow={() => true} />
     </div>
      <div className="SignupLoginContainer__Form_Container">
        <Login isLoggingInOrSigningUp={true} />
      </div>
       </div>
  </Fragment>
    )).toBeTrue()
```

Here's my component render method:

```js
render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
          <div className={styles.SignupLoginContainer}>
            <div className={styles.SignupLoginContainer__SliderBtnContainer}>
              <LoginSignupSliderButton toShow={(val: boolean) => this.toLogInOrSignUp(val)} />
            </div>
            <div className={styles.SignupLoginContainer__Form_Container}>
              <Login isLoggingInOrSigningUp={this.state.toLoginOrSignup} />
            </div>
          </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

My test works if I remove `<LoginSignupSliderButton toShow={(val: boolean) => this.toLogInOrSignUp(val)} />` from the component and test.

I'm suspecting because of the callback?

Comment: Hi aRtoo. I have corrected a number of your post spellings over time, and I wonder if you could now start to run your material through an English spell-checker. They are available to plug in to browsers free of charge these days. Remember that editors are a volunteer resource, and we don't want to keep fixing the same errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `snapshot testing` like so:

```js
// yourcomp.test.js

import YourComp from './wherever-it-lives';


it('renders correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<YourComp/>);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

After this test passes, it will create a `__snapshots__` folder in your project directory with the correct snapshot for your components markup.

NOTE: If you ever update your markup (HTML) again, this test will fail until you update your snapshot like so:

```sh
jest --updateSnapshot
```

And your test should be passing again.

PS. I have of course made an assumption you are using jest as your test runner.

Comment: why do i need snapshot? I want to isolate the test though. it might be confusing if i create a test for the whole structure? yes sir im using jest. thank you for your response

Comment: if you do shallow rendering (like i have shown in the example), then you will only be re-producing the markup of your component. You need snapshot testing so you don't have to worry about matching things manually all the time.

Comment: You are assuming OP is using `Jest` (for the `toMatchSnapshot`) which is a jest-only method